# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\System Volume Information' at Error (native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, relayjs

I am a beginner in react, relay and graphQL I was able to create a good graphql schema file and implemented relay successfully as well but got stuck with react issue. 
I am using babel loader in webpack to help me convert jsx into js, but it seems some syntax error which babel cant understand.

here are my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
"babel-core": "^6.21.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"babel-relay-plugin": "^0.10.0",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"express-graphql": "^0.5.4",
"graphql": "^0.6.2",
"promise": "^7.1.1",
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-relay": "^0.10.0",
"webpack": "^1.13.1"
```

},
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }

and here is my app.js file code

```
export default class Comp1 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
    <input type = "text"
        placeholder = "Start Typing"
        value = {this.props.searchTerm}
        onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this, 'searchTerm')} />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
    );
    }
}

class Comp2 extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.props.info.text}
    </div>
    );
    }
}
```

here is my error

> webpack: bundle is now VALID.

express:router dispatching GET / +7s

express:router query  : / +3ms

express:router expressInit  : / +2ms

express:router webpackDevMiddleware  : / +2ms

express:router   : / +3ms

express:router webpackDevMiddleware  : / +3ms

send stat "D:\index.html" +2ms

serve-index stat "D:\" +2ms

serve-index readdir "D:\" +0ms

express:router serveStatic  : / +5ms

finalhandler default 500 +2ms

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\System Volume Information'
    at Error (native)

Please provide your valuable suggestions and help me to sort out this as I have already invested too much time on it.

Kind Regards,
Yashpal

Comment: Can you post your  Babel configuration? I assume you either didn't configure Babel at all or you forgot to add the react preset.

Comment: Please bear with me I have no clue which configuration file you are asking, could you please specify the name of the file.

Comment: Where the configuration is mostly depends on how you actually invoke Babe, but typically you'd have a `.babelrc` file. I suggest to read https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/ and https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/ .

Comment: still have the issue ??

Comment: yes issue is still there.:(

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have missed the babel configuration in your webpack.config.js file.

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.js$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' 
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry that error is on <form tag because of editing it moved to onSubmit function.

Comment: I tried your code I can run it without getting any error.I suggest please write blank functions in the class for handleSubmit and handleChange.It will not throw error.

One question.Do you get the error in bundling or at the run time in the console.

Comment: I get this while building so don't what dependency I am missing here.:(

Comment: Yes your bundler checks for the defined functions also.If you bind some function and not defined any where in the class it will show the same place where it is written.So your handleSubmit function written in onSubmit is not defined in the class.So it is throwing error.So please define the functions and run it.It will get resolved.

Comment: I defined the function there but still same error and here is code                              handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value});
 }

 handleSubmit(event) {
  alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
  event.preventDefault();
 }

Comment: I just added the configuration you sent in comment in webpack.config.js file but still same error.

Comment: Why there are 2 babel-cli mentioned in your package.json file ?

Comment: I have no clue about that might be I installed them in past but does it impact that ?